# I'm trying to scale only one loop in edit mode but when i select that loop and try to scale, it scales the entire mesh. What should i do?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, scale

I am a beginner in blender and I made a cylinder mesh then I went into the edit mode to scale only the base loop but everytime I try, it scales the entire mesh.
I tried selecting only vertices or edges and both of them together but it made no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe disable the Proportional Editing mode button (blue sphere icon on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of your 3D View)

Comment: @moonboots it works now thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *Proportional Editing mode* button (blue sphere icon on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of your 3D View).